# Not working, display javascript variable in html

Tags: javascript, html

Simple question, the variable total is not being displayed in the html page, could you please tell me why this is not working? I am quite new to coding.

```
 var addtime = [0,2];

 function totaltime(){
  var total = 0;
   for(var i in addtime) {
     total += addtime[i];
   }
   document.getElementById("totalTime").innerHTML = total;
 }
```

html

```
<h1>Total Time: <span id="totalTime"></span></h1>
```

Comment: You are not calling/invoking the function, call like `totaltime();`

Comment: a function is a part of your code that is **declared**, for further uses. in your example , you only declared it, not use. to **call** it , you need to use it in a portion of your code that isn't the function déclaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing call the function `totaltime();`

```js
var addtime = [0,2];

function totaltime(){
   var total = 0;
   for(var i in addtime) {
      total += addtime[i];
   }
   document.getElementById("totalTime").innerHTML = total;
 }
 
 totaltime();
```

```html
   <h1>Total Time: <span id="totalTime"></span></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't call the function

```js
var addtime = [0,2];

 function totaltime(){
  var total = 0;
   for(var i in addtime) {
      total += addtime[i];
     }
     document.getElementById("totalTime").innerHTML = total;
 }

totaltime()
```

```html
<h1>Total Time: <span id="totalTime"></span></h1>
```